# How to name arrays or list when the nouns are both singular and plural?

Tags: naming

Generally variables are named in the singular `Car car;` and arrays and list with the pluras: `List<Car> cars;` or `Car[] cars;` But what about nouns like `fish` or `media`* that are already plural?

*already lost the battle to have the class called `Medium`.

Comment: "fishes" is an acceptable plural form of of "fish", at least.

Comment: I often use `carList` / `carArray`

Comment: I have to agree with @BryanChen. It is very easy to use standard English plurals but being a natural language there are many irregular words. Programming is logical. If ever there needed to be a way to automate getting or setting of words, it would be very difficult to do with standard pluralization. I support using carList, fishList, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this problem.  None of them are perfect, but you can find a workable solution.  The key is that your team needs to come up with a standard approach to resolving this and to stick with it.

Here are some of the options:

- Different capitalization

The singularly named variable will start with one case (lower case) while the plural variable will start with the other case (upper case).

```
 var Fish = new List<fish>();  //plural  
 var fish = Fish[0];           //singular
```

- Deliberate use of improper grammar

Example:

```
 var Fishes = new List<fish>();  //plural  
 var fish = Fishes[0];           //singular
```

or

```
 var Meese = new List<Moose>();  //plural  
 var Moose = Meese[0];           //singular
```

- Use group name instead

Example:

```
 var SchoolOfFish = new List<Fish>();  //plural  
 var Fish = SchoolOfFish[0];           //singular
```

Comment: Uppercase names are usually reserved for types/classes, etc!

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to try to use a more meaningful name for the list variables.  I know this is sometimes hard to do, though.

For example, instead of `List<Car> cars`, use something like `List<Car> parkedCars`.  Instead of `Fish[] fish`, use something like `Fish[] availableFish`.

Comment: but each fish in the array of `availableFish` is also an `availableFish`. I don't think is a great solution.

Comment: The point is to use descriptive words to compose variable names. If you name the array `availableFish` and need another variable to hold one of the items in the array, well then you just need to choose a different appropriate descriptive word. Perhaps `selectedFish` would work. If not that, then something else. Use a thesaurus to find the right word. If nothing else, you could even just use `fish` for a limited-scope variable, because the name wasn't already taken for the array.

Comment: @totty-js No, there is no "array *of* `availableFish`" in the code above. An array *of* `availableFish`-s means `availableFish[] insertvariablenamehere;`. The only reason you're creating confusion is because you're using an inaccurate English description of the code. Some accurate English readings of the code include: "there is an array, `availableFish`", "there is an array named `availableFish`", "there is a `Fish` array named `availableFish` which contains the available `Fish` objects"...

Comment: A correct sentence that follows the same form as the sentence in your comment would be "each `Fish` in the array *`availableFish`* is a `Fish`".

Answer (score 4):

I think names like `List<Fish> fish` are perfectly fine. We use "fish" as both singular an plural in writing; why not do the same in code?

If you want a singular `Fish fish` in the same scope, say for iterating, can always switch to `List<Fish> fishList` or `List<Fish> listOfFish`.

Comment: List<Fish> school

Comment: mostly because often you haves code conventions like `for( Book book : books )` so the singular is already taken or going to be used for something else.

Comment: `fishList` or `listOfFish` is not perfect because it is coupled to the implementation. If `List` is changed to `Collection` or `Set` the name implies something that is no longer the case.

Comment: @basseur I see your point, but it's not really an implementation detail, since `List` and `Set` are interfaces with somewhat different properties. Arguably it would be appropriate to rename `fishList` → `fishSet` to reflect the change in semantics.